# How to check testnet address balance

Tags: testnet, blockchain-explorer

I have an address mpc1rKeaMSCuQnJevMViLuq8uWjHwgdjiV
I check it via json rpc and get balance = 4.6 with 6 confirmations 
When I check http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/address/mpc1rKeaMSCuQnJevMViLuq8uWjHwgdjiV
I get nothing.. is it OK ?

Comment: I’ve collected all of the below mentioned testnet block explorers in the linked community wiki today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The testnet Block Explorer doesn't seem to be working. If you go to http://blockexplorer.com/testnet, the most recent block it shows is from August 29, about two weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

BTC Look's Testnet is still online. Try http://testnet.btclook.com/addr/mpc1rKeaMSCuQnJevMViLuq8uWjHwgdjiV.

Comment: not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Blockr.io Bitcoin TESTNET](http://tbtc.blockr.io/)

[image]

Comment: not working anymore in 2021

Answer (score 1):

BlockStream and BlockCypher are useful:

https://blockstream.info/testnet/address/tb1qhmwlez06e5p78lnycypnaqctcuczhmznwhq5zu

https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/address/tb1q4mcpay7xczhqnj5gpcz5eckw0rjlr35tkezw45/

Comment: Thanks, I started a community wiki to keep a list of testnet explorers here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/121054/where-can-i-find-a-testnet-or-signet-explorer

Answer (score 0):

A reasonably fast & stable testnet API I could find is Blocktrail

JSON
https://api.blocktrail.com/v1/tbtc/address/mpA7LkZe8TKNMgTPJVbn5StQ6Yh28fXg1d?api_key=MY_APIKEY

HTML
https://www.blocktrail.com/tBTC/address/mpA7LkZe8TKNMgTPJVbn5StQ6Yh28fXg1d/transactions

Comment: site is dead in 2021

Answer (score 0):

The Block Cypher website has a testnet blockchain explorer. https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/