# Where can I find a testnet or signet explorer?

Tags: testnet, blockchain-explorer, signet, canonical-question

We have several questions that boil down to "where can I find a testnet explorer?". Unfortunately, most of the answers on those questions are outdated.

I’ve started this community wiki to keep one **up-to-date list of testnet and signet explorers** in a single place. Please help to collect information from answers on prior topics and close those as a duplicate to this community wiki. Please mark any updates with a date.

Answer (score 0):

*Please update the date when you check every entry, otherwise add a new block with the current date.*

## Testnet explorers

Last checked 2023-12-19:

- [mempool.space/testnet](https://mempool.space/testnet)
- [blockchair.com/bitcoin/testnet](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/testnet)
- [blockstream.info/testnet](https://blockstream.info/testnet/)
- [live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet](https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet)
- [tbtc.bitaps.com](https://tbtc.bitaps.com/)

## Signet explorers

Last checked 2023-12-19:

- [mempool.space/signet](https://mempool.space/signet)
- [explorer.bc-2.jp](https://explorer.bc-2.jp/)

---

#### Defunct Testnet explorers

Last updated: 2023-12-19:

- <s>[testnet.blockchain.info](https://testnet.blockchain.info)</s>
- <s>[testnet.btclook.com](http://testnet.btclook.com)</s>
- <s>[tbtc.blockr.io](http://tbtc.blockr.io/)</s>
- <s>[blocktrail.com/v1/tbtc](https://blocktrail.com/v1/tbtc)</s>
- <s>[explorer.btc.com/tbtc](https://explorer.btc.com/tbtc)</s>
- <s>[blockexplorer.com/l/en-US/testnet](https://www.blockexplorer.com/l/en-US/testnet)</s>
- <s>[test-insight.bitpay.com](https://test-insight.bitpay.com/)</s>
- <s>[testnet.coinprism.info/](https://testnet.coinprism.info/)</s>
- <s>[biteasy.com/testnet](https://www.biteasy.com/testnet/blocks)</s>
- <s>[testnet.smartbit.com.au](https://testnet.smartbit.com.au)</s>